# SQL how to use prepareStatement update specify fields with IsNull for int and double?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I would like to use prepareStatement to update the table. But the input may be null value. By using IsNull, it can only apply to varchar, how about int, double?

I will receive a json object(only the fields need to be update), eg:

```
{                             {
 price: 1.56        OR         name: "aa",         OR     ...
}                              age:10             
                              }
```

For the int and double, if the value didn't set, when I get the value, it will return 0, how can I set it to null when the user didn't pass in to me?

My class :

```
private String name;
private int age;
private double price;
//public get & set method
```

My java:

```
strQuery = "UPDATE table SET name=IsNull(?, name), age=IsNull(?, age), price=IsNull(?, age) WHERE id= ?";
stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
stmt.setString(1, obj.getName()); //string
stmt.setString(2, obj.getAge()); //int
stmt.setString(3, obj.getPrice()); //double
stmt.setString(4, id);
```

My question:

how to catch the json input, if the field(int/double) is not available then set it to null?

I tried to use Double instead of double, it's work, but I'm not sure this is the good way or not. (I'm a complete novice)

OR any other best way to do what I want to do?

Comment: If you want to know nullness, you should use `Integer` and `Double` instead. BTW: This doesn't really seem to be an SQL or JDBC question, it is more one of how you map your JSON.

Comment: Can you share the code for the class, instance of which `obj` represents? Seems like you should represent and identify uninitialized fields using the _null object pattern_.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the objects while setting parameters

```
stmt.setInt(2, obj.getAge() != 0 ? obj.getAge() : null);
stmt.setDouble(3, obj.getPrice() != 0 ? obj.getPrice() : null);
```

Now, as you stated using Double it works because class objects are by default assigned as null during initialization. However, primitive types gets assigned default values. e.g., int-0, double-0.0, bool-false etc. You can check more on it. Either approach works using wrapper classes or comparison while setting parameters. But the better would be comparison.

Comment: How do you know that value `0` is supposed to represent `null` and not actual `0`? That seems to be the core of the problem.

Comment: Well, in that case switch to use Double and Integer which sets to null if not specified. We can't consider 0 as null but you can choose some temporary value(Double.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE) to be set as default in case you really want to work with primitives. But the best would be to use object(Double/Integer).

Comment: That was the point of my comment: your answer did not (and still doesn't) really address the problem.

Comment: If you have a better solution. Please post. This solution solves the requirement of setting null I don't see any flaw.